# Getting "undefined" on response.d MVC ASP.NET Core Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I´m trying to create a datatable using Ajax, but before creating and filling the data table with the ajax response, on success I send an alert with "response.d" it returns undefined and thats why im not filling the data table.

Script

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabHistorialTrabajos').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Monitoreo/GetData",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //success: OnSuccess,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            $("datatableTrabajos").DataTable(
                {
                    blengthchange: true,
                    lengthmenu: [[5, 10, -1], [5, 10, "all"]],
                    bfilter: true,
                    bsort: true,
                    bpaginate: true,
                    data: response.d,
                    columns: [{ 'data': 'idTrabajo' },
                        { 'data': 'idTurnoXMaquina' },
                        { 'data': 'parte' },
                        { 'data': 'cliente' },
                        { 'data': 'cantidadPedido' },
                        { 'data': 'cantidadMerma' },
                        { 'data': 'cantidadTarimas' },
                        { 'data': 'fechaInicio' },
                        { 'data': 'fechaFin' },
                        { 'data': 'cantidadFabricado' },
                        { 'data': 'tiempoMuerto' },
                        { 'data': 'velocidad' },
                        { 'data': 'fabricado' }
                    ]
                });
        };
    </script>
```

Controller (returns a JSON)

```
public string GetData()
        {
            ServiciosMenu serviciosMenu = new ServiciosMenu();
            List<CorridaModel> listadoTrabajosXMaquina = serviciosMenu.GetHistorialTrabajosXMaquina(4);
            string JsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listadoTrabajosXMaquina);
            return JsonResult;
        }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: So what's the value of `response`?  Why would it be `.d`?

Comment: Sorry, i´m a little nooby in the use of jquery/ajax. I saw it on a article where they teach how to use datatable with ajax and they use .d to access data

Comment: No worries, it'll be whatever you create it as from your GetData() server method.   Most likely, if you're providing the correct format, you can use just `data: response,`  - but datatables will need the data in the correct format and it's unclear (unlikely?) if `GetHistorialTrabajosXMaquina()` is formatting it as required by datatables.

Comment: My GetData controller is returing only a JSON, and that JSON I´m trying to assigne it to the data of DataTable

Comment: Yes, but "JSON" contains data, you can't just randomly assign "data" and hope everything works.

Comment: Yes I understand, i make a test and print at console my "response" it contains an array of 98 elements, so the controller is returning the information in a correct format.

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

We need to change the default value of `maxJsonLength`. I learned from github that the default value of this maxJsonLength is 30M.

**And suggestion for yor method in Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    List<TestPersonModel> list = new List<TestPersonModel>();
    TestPersonModel m = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        m = new TestPersonModel();
        m.name = "John" + i;
        m.age =  i+1;
        m.car = "car" + i;
        list.Add(m);
    }
    return Json(list);
}
public class TestPersonModel { 
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string car { get; set; }
}
```

Under normal circumstances, we do not return `string` types, but generally return `Json` types.

*Since the length of the string of your return type is not clear, it is possible that the current problem can be solved by the above code.*

If it doesn't work, it is recommended to refer to the link below, or provide the code for the smallest unit that can be reproduced.

[Max Length for Json Object Asp.net Core 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66924661/max-length-for-json-object-asp-net-core-3-1)